# DateTime::createFromFormat is not working as I want

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a date in this format: Wednesday, 21 May, 2014.

To save this date in database I´m trying to convert it to datetime, like this:

```
$f['date'] = $_POST['date'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $f['date']); 
$date = $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Then I´ll insert $date in my database, and works fine, date is saved like datetime in database.

But now I want to show date, so I want to transform it again, in this format: "Wednesday, 21 May, 2014".

For this, Im doing my select and then I use again DateTime::createFormat to convert date, from datetime to my "text format":

```
$readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM news");
$readNews->execute();
while ($readNewsResult  = $readNews->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l, j F, Y', $readNewsResult['date']);
   ..... //here I have more echos showing title of the news, etc
   echo '<span class="date">'.$date.'</span>';
}
```

The problem Im having is that date it isn´t appearing...

Do you see what Im doing wrong here?

Comment: When the date comes out of your database, it is not in the format `'l, j F, Y'` - so the `createFromFormat` in your `while` loop gets confused. Remember, in `createFromFormat`, you're telling it what format to expect, not what format you want it to be.

Comment: +1 for actually using `DateTime()` and not creating some `strtotime()` monstrosity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `DateTime::createFromFormat()` here. You only need to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` when you have a date in a format PHP doesn't understand. You already have a format `DateTime()` can handle.

So all you need to do is change the format when you print it out which you will use [`DateTime::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for:

```
$date = new DateTime($readNewsResult['date']);
echo '<span class="date">'.$date->format('l, j F, Y').'</span>';
```